# How to change display suite extra default permissions?

Tags: display-suite

I am having problems with diplay suite extra module.

Every time I create a dynamic field, it only shows up for logged in users.

So I have to manually go to permissions, look for the content type, can change to anonymous users.

This is highly annoying and wastes a lot of time.

How can I set permissions for ALL content to be view able by anonymous users.

My website is not private, I need all content to be available publicly, by default!

[image]

Comment: Can't you just disable this field level permissions functionality provided by this module or do you need to set permissions for other non-anonymous users?

Comment: The permissions on your screen shot are not from display suite nor from display suite extra. You must have installed some other module which is causing your issue.

Comment: Wrong screen shot, but still you can see that all views, author, picture, date modified, ALL of it set to only admin...